# &#65279 is giving weird spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a website that looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>Par&#65279;agra&#65279;ph 1</p> 
</div>
```

but when I try to print it in Python:

```
for paragraph in div.find_all("p"):
  print(paragraph.text)
```

It comes out like this:

> Par agra ph 1

How can I remove the `&#65279` spaces without removing the intended space?

EDIT
Here is my code

```
srcu = urllib.request.urlopen("url").read();
src = bs.BeautifulSoup(srcu, "lxml")

for paragraph in src.find_all("p"):
    a = pragraph.text
    print(a)



exit()
```

Comment: yes i am using BeautifulSoup

Comment: That is the ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF). You can replace it just like you would any other character.

Comment: usr2564301 that doesn't work but maybe i am doing it wrong. a = a.replace("U+FEFF", "") ?

Comment: ... You *are* doing it wrong. There is no literal text `U+FEFF` for that character. Look up in the documentation how to specify unicode literals in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The following would work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div>
  <p>Par&#65279;agra&#65279;ph 1</p> 
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.text.replace('\uFEFF', ''))
```

Giving you:

```
Paragraph 1
```